# How do I find a the crew_chief with most services provided?

Tags: mysql

I need to find the crew chief who has provided the most services. I have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE JasperGreen.PROVIDED_SERVICE (
    PROVISION INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
    CONTRACT_ID INT NOT NULL,
    PROVISION_DATE DATE NOT NULL,
    CREW_CHIEF INT NOT NULL,
    CUST_ID INT NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PROVIDED_SERVICE_FK1 FOREIGN KEY(CUST_ID) REFERENCES CUSTOMER(CUST_ID),
    CONSTRAINT PROVIDED_SERVICE_FK2 FOREIGN KEY(CONTRACT_ID) REFERENCES CONTRACTED_SERVICE(CONTRACT_ID),
    CONSTRAINT PROVIDED_SERVICE_PK PRIMARY KEY (PROVISION)
);
```

So far I ran this query and it's returning an error:

```
SELECT CREW_CHIEF, COUNT(provision)
FROM PROVIDED_SERVICE
WHERE provision = 
    (SELECT MAX(COUNT(provision)) FROM PROVIDED_SERVICE)
```

> Error 1111: Invalid use of a group function.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

```
select CREW_CHIEF, count(provision)
from PROVIDED_SERVICE
GROUP BY CREW_CHIEF
ORDER BY count(provision) DESC
LIMIT 1
```

You cant nest `MAX` and `COUNT`. if you want use your method, need add group by

```
select CREW_CHIEF, count(provision)
from PROVIDED_SERVICE
group by CREW_CHIEF
HAVING count(provision) = 
       (select count(provision)  
        from PROVIDED_SERVICE
        group by CREW_CHIEF
        order by count(provision) desc
        limit 1
       )
```

EDIT:

As Tim points out. The first query return a random chef in case of ties. The second one return all chefs ties with the max count.

Comment: is there a way to do this using max function?

Comment: You cant nest max and count function. You get the count after you already group by.

Answer (score 0):

Juan's answer is good if you only want a single top chef, or, in the event of a tie for first place, you don't care which chef gets returned.  Continuing with your current approach, we can get all chefs in first place including ties:

```
SELECT CREW_CHIEF, COUNT(*) AS cnt
FROM PROVIDED_SERVICE
GROUP BY CREW_CHIEF
HAVING COUNT(*) = (
    SELECT MAX(cnt) FROM (
        SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM PROVIDED_SERVICE GROUP BY CREW_CHIEF) t );
```

### Demo

Comment: This is what I mean you cant nest count and max. You need to use a subquery to get the count so you can then apply the max.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza My query [seems to work fine](http://rextester.com/ZJC51023).  Can you clairfy what is wrong with it?

Comment: Sorry. That was mean to OP. He ask me if he could use MAX(Count())